# ggplot grid with constant x-axis scale but varying axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Take a look at the following plotting code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
a <- data.frame(a1=1:10, a2=1:10)
b <- data.frame(b1=1:5, b2=2*(1:5))
aplot <- ggplot(a, aes(x=a1, ymin=0, ymax=12)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=a2))
bplot <- ggplot(b, aes(x=b1, ymin=0, ymax=12)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=b2))
plot_grid(aplot,bplot, ncol=2)
```

It yields two side-by-side plots of identical dimensions showing similar lines.  But the x-axis scales are rather different.  In fact, the second line has twice the slope of the first.

I am looking for a way to plot this figure so that the width of a plot is scaled by the limits of its x-axis, so that the slopes can be compared visually.  The real plots I am interested in visualizing are five in number and will lack y-axis labels except for the leftmost.  I can use `grid.arrange()` to plot them all in a row with whatever widths I want, but the problem is that I don't know what width to assign to each panel to make sure they come out right (the panel width has to be large enough to accommodate the plot margins, the y-axis tick marks, and the y-axis text).  I can set the margins myself and account for them in my panel widths, but I cannot find a good way to figure out how wide (e.g. in cm) the y-axis text is.

Comment: Hm, what if we set the x-axis' maximum point as the same for the both plots ? It's different than your original intention, but we can still compare the different slopes

Comment: sounds like using facetting and space="free" would be a better option

Comment: @zyurnaidi In the case I am dealing with (trying to make a figure for a paper), it would be an unacceptable waste of space to use the maximum x-axis span in every panel, when several panels span only a quarter of the maximum range.

Comment: @baptiste looks like faceting will lead to what I want; I will tinker a bit and see what I can do. Thanks.

Comment: @baptiste What if I need to customize each panel a bit, for example if I want to draw a few extra points on just one panel.  Is there a natural way to do this with `facet_grid()`?

Comment: yes, you need to create a data.frame with the relevant data and pass it to the  geom_point layer of annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rel_widths option in plot_grid to achieve this.  You need to calculate the relative size you want each plot to be using the ratio of the ranges xmax-xmin of each panel. But, there is an extra catch. rel_widths sets the relative width of the whole panel, including the margins. So we also need to account for the margins in calculating the relative size. In the following code, adding an offset value of 2 to the numerator and denominator of relative.size works for this. But note that this offset value may change if you alter the size of the margins.

```
aplot <- ggplot(a, aes(x=a1, ymin=0, ymax=12, xmin=0, xmax=max(a$a1))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=a2))

bplot <- ggplot(b, aes(x=b1, ymin=0, ymax=12, xmin=0, xmax=max(b$b1))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=b2))

relative.size <- (2+max(b$b1)) / (2+max(a$a1)) # the addition of 2 here is to account for the plot margins
plot_grid(aplot,bplot, ncol=2, rel_widths=c(1,relative.size), align = "h")
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I may be off-base here, but I believe that there is an extra bit of accounting that needs to be done.  Beyond the x-limits, these plots have margins (which we can control as you indicate), but they also have axis text. How wide is "12.5"?  The answer depends on the font-size and also the font, and in general I don't think it's straightforward to determine what the width of the typeset "12.5" is (it is also necessary to add back the length of the tick mark, but this is easer).  Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @JacobSocolar you're right. I'm not sure right now how to automatically do this calculation - let me give it some more thought. If you only have a few plots to do, you can manually measure the width of the ticks plus labels in x-axis units. In the mean time I leave this answer up as it is close to what you want and may be useful to others as one approach. If I work out how to automate this calculation, I'll update this answer.